# Software that set a Internet limit on other software for Android

Tags: android, internet

Is there a software for Android 7.x Nougat that can set a Internet (regardless data or wifi) limit on each and every Apps?

Requirements:

- gratis
- set Internet limit for individual apps (including stock apps)
- default Internet limit for apps is 0 (meaning no Internet for all apps by default)
- send a notification or popup message when the individual apps had hit its Internet limit. (e.g. If an app is given 5 MB of Internet, once the 5 MB is used, a notification will be displayed on the screen)
- allow warning notification or popup message. (e.g. set a 2 MB as warning limit and a hard limit of 5 MB, when the app used 2 MB, it display a warning notification on the screen.)
- **disconnect the app from the Internet completely without question if it hit the max hard limit. (Important)**
- **does not require user to root their phone (and this is a very important requirement)**
- can support Android version below 7 or above 7 (but must be able to use on a Android 7.x Nougat phone)
- able to reset the Internet usage for individual apps to allow better management (as it is no point to keep increase the hard limit.)

Thank you.